# Existence of infinitely many different arithmetic sequences of length n

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> For every positive integer $n$, the are infinitely many different arithmetic sequences of length $n$, $\{a,a+d,a+2d, \cdots, a+(n-1)d \}$, all terms of which are prime. Prove or disprove.

I think that the Green-Tao theorem will help here. But I can't find a way to do this. I am not advanced in dealing with number theories. Therefore, I just assume truth in the Green-Tao theorem but wish to solve it using elementary number theory.

I strictly want a hint and not a solution.

Comment: Hint: Use Green-Tao theorem, and construct some increasing sequence $n_1,n_2,\cdots$, and extract first arithmetic prime sequences of length $n_i$.